# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: attributes, kivy, clock

i have a issue which i cant solve.

When i run the following code i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Everything works fine till i ad a Clock.schedule

Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

global C
C = 0




class Example(App):
     def build(self):
          global C
          C = C + 1
          y = str(C)
          self.root = FloatLayout()
          self.label = Label(text=y, pos=(0,0), size_hint=(1.0,1.0), halign="left")


      self.label.text_size = self.label.size
      self.root.add_widget(self.label)
      return self.root
      Clock.schedule_once(build, 0.1)

Example().run()
```

For Example: When i want to update the time, i call a method every second with

#Clock.schedule_interval(test, 1)

So i call the Method every second

But if i want to update the time and send it to a lable with the ID time i get the same error....

```
def test(self):
    z = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.ids.time.text = (y)
```

Clock.schedule_interval(test, 1)

My goal in this projekt is to show the time on every page and update the status of different inputs on different screens to lables for example every second.

i tried the following command to but i guess it doesnt work for more then one screen

self.the_time.text = MyTime

Comment: Are you sure you want to return before doing whatever Clock.schedule_once() does?

Comment: i gues it doesnt matter, i have this error in a a lot of methods in my main projekt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` is a method, and as such be called as `self.build`, also, it should accept a float argument for the elapsed time since the scheduling.

I assume what happens is that the method is called unbound (no implicit self) and self is assigned that float value, so the method tries to work with that float as `self`, which doesn't work for pretty obvious reasons.

TL&DR: use `Clock.schedule_once(self.build, 0.1)` and change `build` declaration to something like `def build(self, dt=0):`.